# Why I get p-value equal to NA

Tags: r

I am doing the  Distance Covariance Test and Distance Correlation test using `energy` package.

The test is giving this result :

```
> test<-dcov.test(DATA_CATEG[1:nrow(DATA_CATEG),15],
+                 DATA_CATEG[1:nrow(DATA_CATEG),3])
> test

    Specify the number of replicates R (R > 0) to perform the test of independence

data:  index 1, replicates 0
nV^2 = 25.986, p-value = NA
sample estimates:
     dCov 
0.1248535
```

Is it a programming issue or what?? Assuming that my dataset is clean and it does not have any NA values.

This is to make it reproductible :

```
    > dput(DATA_CATEG[1:20,c(3,15)])
structure(c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 3L, 9L, 26L, 
17L, 22L, 13L, 10L, 30L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 14L, 16L), .Dim = c(20L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("IMPERFECTIONS", "OUTCOME")))
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Your output shows that you forgot to specify `R` parameter for test. Try again with this parameter - maybe test cannot be performed without it.

Comment: Documentation suggests some values for `R` and links to more on the topic: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/energy/versions/1.7-4/topics/dcov.test

Comment: @franiis, thank you!

Comment: Did it help? I'll post an answer if so :)

Comment: @franiis,yes it is

Comment: It's unclear from reading `energy::dcov.test()` whether their R=NULL parameter default is useable, but if not the function needs a warning. Either way they need to improve the documentation, you could file a docbug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to specify `R` parameter. This method requires it.

You can find more on the topic in documentation (suggested values and some literature on the topic):
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/energy/versions/1.7-4/topics/dcov.test